# how to import several express middleware from one module?

Tags: express

I am quite new with typescript/express and I have a problem with importing a middleware.

Indeed, I have a module `auth.ts` which will contain in a near future several middlewares. Here is its current implementation (with only one middleware for keeping simple).

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";

export function getConnectedPerson(req: Request, res: Response, next) {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const { personId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SEED) as JwtPayload;
        res.locals.personId = personId;
        next();
    } catch {
        res.status(401).send("Invalid request");
    }
}
```

and here is my controller implementation:

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import { autoInjectable } from "tsyringe";

const authMiddleware = require("auth")

@autoInjectable()
export class ActivityController {
    constructor() {
    }

    initRoutes(router: Router) {
        
        router.get('/activities', [
            authMiddleware.getConnectedPerson
        ],async (req: Request, res: Response) => {});
    }
}
```

when starting my app, I get the following error:

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
```

I am a bit lost with all the possible import/export/require variants. Would you know what is wrong with my implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In auth.ts, export is going wrong i feel. Please do the following changes and try

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";

function getConnectedPerson(req: Request, res: Response, next) {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const { personId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SEED) as JwtPayload;
        res.locals.personId = personId;
        next();
    } catch {
        res.status(401).send("Invalid request");
    }
}

function getConnectedPerson_1(req: Request, res: Response, next) {
  // some operation
  console.log("second function export");
  next();
}

exports.getConnectedPerson = getConnectedPerson;
exports.getConnectedPerson_1 = getConnectedPerson_1;
```

in controller :-

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import { autoInjectable } from "tsyringe";

//const authMiddleware = require("auth")
const { getConnectedPerson, getConnectedPerson_1 } =require("./auth")

@autoInjectable()
export class ActivityController {
    constructor() {
    }

    initRoutes(router: Router) {
        
        router.get('/activities', [ getConnectedPerson, getConnectedPerson_1 ],async (req: Request, res: Response) => {});
    }
```

}

Comment: thanks for the hint. However, with your solution, I can implement only one function per module and I want to have several function in my module to be exported.

Comment: You can have any number of functions in a module and export them. That's not an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately when I implement your suggestion it works but only as long as I declare only one function. As soon as I declare a second function I get the same error message: `Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]`

Comment: Please check the updated code. I have exported multiple functions from with auth middleware.

Comment: my bad, the problem was due a typo